# How to declare a global variable in this API?

Tags: php, apache, try-catch

My application has a `production` or `development` setting that I can toggle. When setting up the server, I set up this flag in `Applications > Mamp > Conf > Apache > httpd.conf`. Its purpose is to give my local API directory a server alias. It also defines the document root etc.

```
Listen 44447

<VirtualHost *:44447>
DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api"
ServerName 192.168.1.5:44447
ServerAlias pushchat.local
CustomLog "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/log/apache_access.log" combined
ErrorLog "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/log/apache_error.log"

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

<Directory "/Users/user/Desktop/PushChatServer/api">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My goal is to set up a global variable in my api and pass it to another file. The php file my app uses is called `api.php` and I'd  like to use a global variable named `$Var1`. I set up `$Var1` like this in `api.php`

```
//In api.php
global $Var1;
$Var1 = '1';
```

When I try to call it, no out put is received. I am calling it like this:

```
<?php

 //Checks for warnings
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

include 'api.php'

echo "Var1";

?>
```

The thing is no output at all is echoed in the browser. I now realize the code block in `api.php` that is interfering with the global variable.  I still am not sure why though. When I delete this code block from `api.php` the global variable is successfully displayed in `Test.php`. How can I keep the code block and successfully display the global in `Test.php`?

```
try 
{
// Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily switch
// between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');

// In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
// know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
// expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
// will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
// a good idea to keep an eye on them.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
}

// Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
// separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
// just want to change some settings.
require_once 'api_config.php';
$config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

// In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
// You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
// mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    sleep(0);
// To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
// instance of that class and let it handle the request.

$api = new API($config);
$api->handleCommand();

echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{
switch ($error_code)
{
    case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
    case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
    case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
    case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
}
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

if ($message != '')
    header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);
exit;
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{

if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
    return false;

if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
    return false;

// Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
{
    $ord = ord($string{$t});

    if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
        continue;

    if ($ord < 32)
        return false;
}

return true;
}

function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
$origString = $string;
$origLength = $maxLength;

while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
{
    $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
    $maxLength--;
}

return $string;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Full source code of api.php. My goal is to declare a global variable and pass it a long using a require statement to a new file. I am only able to do so if I delete the entire try block at the beginning of this file and I need to know why.

```
<?php

global $Var1;
$Var1 = '1';    

// This is the server API for the PushChat iPhone app. To use the API, the app
// sends an HTTP POST request to our URL. The POST data contains a field "cmd"
// that indicates what API command should be executed.

try 
{
// Are we running in development or production mode? You can easily     switch
// between these two in the Apache VirtualHost configuration.
if (!defined('APPLICATION_ENV'))
    define('APPLICATION_ENV', getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production');

// In development mode, we show all errors because we obviously want to 
// know about them. We don't do this in production mode because that might
// expose critical details of our app or our database. Critical PHP errors
// will still be logged in the PHP and Apache error logs, so it's always
// a good idea to keep an eye on them.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

}
else
{
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
}

// Load the config file. I prefer to keep all configuration settings in a
// separate file so you don't have to mess around in the main code if you
// just want to change some settings.
require_once 'api_config.php';
$config = $config[APPLICATION_ENV];

// In development mode, we fake a delay that makes testing more realistic.
// You're probably running this on a fast local server but in production
// mode people will be using it on a mobile device over a slow connection.
if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    sleep(0);
// To keep the code clean, I put the API into its own class. Create an
// instance of that class and let it handle the request.

$api = new API($config);
$api->handleCommand();

echo "OK" . PHP_EOL;

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
// The code throws an exception when something goes horribly wrong; e.g.
// no connection to the database could be made. In development mode, we
// show these exception messages. In production mode, we simply return a
// "500 Server Error" message.

if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development')
    var_dump($e);
else
    exitWithHttpError(500);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function exitWithHttpError($error_code, $message = '')
{
switch ($error_code)
{
    case 400: header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"); break;
    case 403: header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden"); break;
    case 404: header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); break;
    case 500: header("HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error"); break;
}
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

if ($message != '')
    header('X-Error-Description: ' . $message);
exit;
}

function isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{

if (empty($string) || strlen($string) > $maxLength)
    return false;

if (mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8') === false)
    return false;

// Don't allow control characters, except possibly newlines 
for ($t = 0; $t < strlen($string); $t++)
{
    $ord = ord($string{$t});

    if ($allowNewlines && ($ord == 10 || $ord == 13))
        continue;

    if ($ord < 32)
        return false;
}

return true;
}

function truncateUtf8($string, $maxLength)
{
$origString = $string;
$origLength = $maxLength;

while (strlen($string) > $origLength)
{
    $string = mb_substr($origString, 0, $maxLength, 'utf-8');
    $maxLength--;
}

return $string;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class API
{
// Because the payload only allows for 256 bytes and there is some overhead
// we limit the message text to 190 characters.
const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 190;

private $pdo;

function __construct($config)
{
    // Create a connection to the database.
    $this->pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], 
        $config['db']['username'], 
        $config['db']['password'],
        array());

    // If there is an error executing database queries, we want PDO to
    // throw an exception. Our exception handler will then exit the script
    // with a "500 Server Error" message.
    $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // We want the database to handle all strings as UTF-8.
    $this->pdo->query('SET NAMES utf8');
}

function handleCommand()
{

    // Figure out which command the client sent and let the corresponding
    // method handle it. If the command is unknown, then exit with an error
    // message.
    if (isset($_POST['cmd']))
    {
        switch (trim($_POST['cmd']))
        {
            case 'join': $this->handleJoin(); return;
            case 'leave': $this->handleLeave(); return;
            case 'update': $this->handleUpdate(); return;
            case 'message': $this->handleMessage(); return;
        }
    }

    exitWithHttpError(400, 'Unknown command');
}

// The "join" API command registers a user to receive notifications that
// are sent in a specific "chat room". Each chat room is identified by a
// secret code. All the users who register with the same secret code can
// see each other's messages.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_Id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters, or "0" if no token is available yet.
// - name:  The nickname of the user. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 255
//          bytes. Only the first 20 bytes are actually shown in the push 
//          notifications.
// - code:  The secret code that identifies the chat room. Must be a UTF-8
//          string of maximum 255 bytes.
//


function handleJoin()
{
    //function getUserId;
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(true);
    $name = $this->getString('name', 255);
    $code = $this->getString('code', 255);

    // When the client sends a "join" command, we add a new record to the
    // active_users table. We identify the client by the user_id that it
    // provides. When the client sends a "leave" command, we delete its
    // record from the active_users table.

    // It is theoretically possible that a client sends a "join" command
    // while its user_id is still present in active_users (because it did not
    // send a "leave" command). In that case, we simply remove the old
    // record first and then insert the new one.

    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO active_users (user_Id, device_token, nickname, secret_code, ip_address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId, $token, $name, $code, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $this->pdo->commit();

}

// The "leave" API command removes a user from a chat room. That user will
// no longer receive push notifications for messages sent to that room.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
//
function handleLeave()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
}

// The "update" API command gives a user a new device token.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id:  A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - token: The device's device token. Must be a string of 64 hexadecimal
//          characters.
//
function handleUpdate()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    $token = $this->getDeviceToken(false);
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE active_users SET device_token = ? WHERE user_Id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($token, $userId));
}

// The "message" API command sends a message to all users who are registered
// with the same secret code as the sender of the message.
//
// This command takes the following POST parameters:
//
// - user_id: A unique identifier. Must be a string of 40 hexadecimal characters.
// - text: The message text. Must be a UTF-8 string of maximum 190 bytes.
//
function handleMessage()
{
    $userId = $this->getUserId();
    /*$text = $this->getString('text', self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, true);*/

    // First, we get the record for the sender of the message from the
    // active_users table. That gives us the nickname, device token, and
    // secret code for that user.

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM active_users WHERE user_Id = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($userId));
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if ($user !== false)
    {
        // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
        // for the push notification.
        $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname/*, $text*/);

        // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
        // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
        // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
        // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM active_users WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
        $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
        $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

        // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
        foreach ($tokens as $token)
        {
            $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
        }
    }
}

// Retrieves the user identifier from the POST data. If the user_id does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getUserId()
{   
    if (!isset($_POST['user_id']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing user_id');

    $userId = trim(urldecode($_POST['user_id']));
    if (!$this->isValidUserId($userId))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid user_id');

    return $userId;
}

// Checks whether the format of the user identifier is correct (40 hex
// characters or 32 for the simulator).
function isValidUserId($userId)
{
    if (strlen($userId) != 40 && strlen($userId) != 32)  // 32 for simulator
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/", $userId) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Retrieves the device token from the POST data. If the token does not
// appear to be valid, the script exits with an error message.
function getDeviceToken($mayBeEmpty = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST['token']))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Missing device token');

    $token = trim($_POST['token']);

    // The "join" command allows a token value of "0" to be specified,
    // which is necessary in case the client did not yet obtain a device
    // token at that point. We allow such clients to join, but they will
    // not receive any notifications until they provide a valid token
    // using the "update" command.
    if ($mayBeEmpty && $token == "0")
        return $token;

    if (!$this->isValidDeviceToken($token))
        exitWithHttpError(400, 'Invalid device token');

    return $token; 

}

// Checks whether the format of the device token is correct (64 hexadecimal
// characters). Note: we have no means to verify whether the device token
// was really issued by APNS and corresponds to an actual device.
function isValidDeviceToken($deviceToken)
{
    if (strlen($deviceToken) != 64)
        return false;

    if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-fA-F]{64}$/", $deviceToken) == 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

// Looks in the POST data for a field with the given name. If the field
// is not a valid UTF-8 string, or it is too long, the script exits with
// an error message.
function getString($name, $maxLength, $allowNewlines = false)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$name]))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Missing $name");

    $string = trim($_POST[$name]);
    if (!isValidUtf8String($string, $maxLength, $allowNewlines))
        exitWithHttpError(400, "Invalid $name");

    return $string;
}

// Creates the JSON payload for the push notification message. The "alert"
// text has the following format: "sender_name: message_text". Recipients
// can obtain the name of the sender by parsing the alert text up to the
// first colon followed by a space.
function makePayload($senderName, $text)
{
    // Convert the nickname of the sender to JSON and truncate to a maximum
    // length of 20 bytes (which may be less than 20 characters).
    $nameJson = $this->jsonEncode($senderName);
    $nameJson = truncateUtf8($nameJson, 20);

    // Convert and truncate the message text
    $textJson = $this->jsonEncode($text);
    $textJson = truncateUtf8($textJson, self::MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH);

    // Combine everything into a JSON string
    $payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"' . $nameJson . ': ' . $textJson . '","sound":"beep.caf"}}';
    return $payload;
}

// We don't use PHP's built-in json_encode() function because it converts
// UTF-8 characters to \uxxxx. That eats up 6 characters in the payload for
// no good reason, as JSON already supports UTF-8 just fine.
function jsonEncode($text)
{
    static $from = array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"');
    static $to = array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"');
    return str_replace($from, $to, $text);
}

// Adds a push notification to the push queue. The notification will not
// be sent immediately. The server runs a separate script, push.php, which 
// periodically checks for new entries in this database table and sends
// them to the APNS servers.
function addPushNotification($deviceToken, $payload)
{
    // Payloads have a maximum size of 256 bytes. If the payload is too
    // large (which shouldn't happen), we won't send this notification.
    if (strlen($payload) <= 256)
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO push_queue (device_token, payload, time_queued) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
        $stmt->execute(array($deviceToken, $payload));
    }

}
}


?>
```

Comment: Just for debuging purposes: What happens when you set `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`  in the else-branch, too and also replace `exitWithHttpError(500);` by `var_dump($e)` ?

Comment: btw: I have a feeling this can go on forever. The other "thread" already has 20+ comments, now this one (which I believe to be a duplicate). I suggest you spin up a debugger+ide, like e.g. [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)

Comment: The syntax errors you'll have to figure out yourself. I can't see what you're actually doing to your source and the comment section of the question doesn't provide any means to communicate the code changes in detail. (+ that's not what stackoverflow is meant for).

Comment: Originally I wasn't able to yet pass any global variables from `api.php` to a `Test.php` file. Now I can , but only after deleting lines 7 - 130 of `api.php`. (the try statement) I posted the full source code above. I'd appreciate it if you can use that info to help pin point how I can keep the try block and successfully use my global variable. Update in progress

Comment: I had to delete my comment about what happened when I added your suggested debugging code to make sure I added it in the right place. I'll give it another go